# What is an elegant way to obtain (variably available) JSON data?

Tags: java, json

I am looking for an elegant way to extract data from a JSON file, should the data be consistent this would be simple to code, however I want to take into account the possibility that it is not.

For example

JSON example 1:

```
...
"years": [{
    "id": 100531911,
    "year": 2012,
    "styles": [{
        "id": 101395591,
        "name": "LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)",
        "submodel": {
            "body": "Convertible",
            "modelName": "Camaro Convertible",
            "niceName": "convertible"
        },
        "trim": "LT"
    }]
}],
...
```

JSON example 2:

```
...
"years": [{
    "year": 2012,
    "styles": [{
        "id": 101395591,
        "name": "LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)",
        "submodel": {
            "body": "Convertible",
        },
        "trim": "LT"
    }]
}],
...
```

As you can see the second JSON example is missing data, so to prevent it I did the following, which is a little messy:

for example if I want to get the "niceName" element. In order to prevent nullpointerexceptions I have to run a series of if statements:

```
if (jsonObj.has("years")) {

    if (jsonObj.getJSONObject("years").has("subModel")) {

        if(jsonObj.getJSONObject("years").getJSONOject("subModel").has("niceName")) {
        //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to approach this?

Comment: It looks pretty clean to me... Clean, self-Documenting and Properly Readable...

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: use jackson.  It maps JSON to objects.  All you need to do is create objects that mimic the structure of the JSON.  @JsonIgnore allows you to ignore unknown properties - meaning you don't have write code to handle whether or not a property is available.

Comment: @shmosel the standard java json library

Comment: @neal thanks, i will take a look

Comment: @NutellaAddict Java doesn't have a standard JSON library.

Comment: or you might like google/gson

Comment: agreed.  gson is a good one, too.

Comment: You could reuse the result of `jsonObj.getJSONObject("years")`. Store it in a variable.